# How to change the key and value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tuples, dictionary-comprehension

So I've got the following code, and what I want to do is take every second value of the inputted tuple, and save it to a dictionary as the `dict.key`, and the `dict.value` set at first to 0. After that I want to go over the saved dictionary and for every time this `dict.key` occurs in the tuple I want to put the count of it in the `dict.value`. The code currently gives me an error.

```
def movie_awards(results):
    """
    I want to ignore every first value of the tuple
    """
    results = list(results)
    
    answer = {x[1]:0 for x in results}
    
    for x in results:
        answer[x[1]] = answer[x] + 1
    
    print(answer)

result = {("Best Picture", "Parasite"),\
          ("Best Actor", "Joker"),\
          ("Best Actress", "Judy"),\
          ("Best Sound Editing", "Ford v Ferrari"),\
          ("Best Sound Editing", "1917"),\
          ("Best Original Score", "Joker"),\
          ("Best Costume Design", "Little Women"),\
          ("Best Visual Effects", "Little Women"),\
          ("Best Director", "Parasite")}
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need all those backslashes at the end of the lines of your definition of `result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the number using `+=`:

```
for x in results:
    answer[x[1]] += 1
    
print(answer)
```

Doing:

```
answer[x]
```

python is trying to fetch the `key:value` pair whose key is `('Best Original Score', 'Joker')`. Since, it doesn't exist, a key error is raised.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def movie_awards(results):
    return Counter(x[1] for x in results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter([t[1] for t in result])

>>> Counter({'Joker': 2, 'Parasite': 2, 'Little Women': 2, '1917': 1, 'Ford v Ferrari': 1, 'Judy': 1})
```